# ¿Como puedo cambiar el icono, en el calendario y el selector?

Tags: angular, npm

Por favor como puedo cambiar los iconos en estas 2 herramientas?

**P-calendar, Datepicker**

```
<label fxFlex="20" class="date-picker_format">
            <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
          </label>
```

**Md-select**

```
 <md-select fxFlex="20" class="input_select"
             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
             [(ngModel)]="timeSelected">
    <md-option *ngFor="let timeSel of time" [value]="timeSel">{{timeSel.value}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando una librería externa. Por lo que bajo mi punto de vista la única forma de modificar el icono del calendario sería accediendo al código de la librería y modificandolo.

El problema de esto es que si ejecutas un nuevo npm-install o actualizas la librería perderías dicho cambio.

La solución a esto sería hacer un wrapper de la librería. Es decir copiarla en tu proyecto fuera de node_modules y modificarla a tu gusto y posteriormente importar dicho componente desde tu proyecto local y no desde la librería.